# Get value from tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter, button

My button

```
button = ttk.Button(frame_file, text='Open file', command=lambda *args: openfile())
button.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

calls a function `openfile()`

```
def openfile():
    return fd.askopenfile()
```

how do I get the path of the opened file in the main (where the button is defined?)

Comment: Why not assigning in similar way as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281280/python-tkinter-button-command-return instead? In this manner I think it would be quite complicated if not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store it in a variable accessible to both functions such as a global variable or an instance attribute. If you want to access it in the same function that creates the button, be aware that the function will likely have returned before the user has had a chance to see and click on the button.

Also, by the way, you can reduce the complexity of your button command by removing `lambda`:

```
button = ttk.Button(frame_file, text='Open file', command=openfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want it?  Tkinter, like most gui libraries, is event-oriented.  The idea is that events should be handled by code called ('fired') when they happen.  If you need to pass state from the button to something else, there are a few options:

global variable:

```py
fn = None
...
def openfile(*args):
    global fn
    fn = ...
```

slightly better: global object:

```py
state = {}
...
def openfile(*args):
    state["fn"] = ...
```

But at this point you have state flying around.  If you really need to do this, you should probably think about encapsulating that state in a *class*, which would handle the action:

```py
class FileDoStuff:
    def __init__(self, row, column, frame_file):
        self.button = ttk.Button(frame_file, "Open File", self.on_click)
        self.button.grid(row, column)
        self.fn = None

    def on_click(self, *args):
        self.fn = ...
```

and as noted in the other answer your lambda isn't doing anything except gobbling arguments, which can be done in the fn itself (as I have here).

Comment: I want to do it because, for example, when I open the file, I want to pass it's path to another function

Comment: But you don't want to call that function on the button press?  In any case, one of these solutions will likely work.

Comment: but how do I link the class with the button?